# Running nested functions using numba

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am trying to use numba recently to speedup parts of my code in python. I was trying to run function 1 from inside function 2 while they are both compiled with numba but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
import numba as nb
from math import acos
from time import time

@nb.jit("void()")
def myfunc():
    s = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        s += acos(0.5)
    print('The sum is: ', s)


@nb.jit("void()")
def myfunc2():
    myfunc()


tic = time()
myfunc2()
toc = time()
print(toc-tic)
```

When I call `myfunc()` the code works and I get a result much faster than when I am not using numba. However, when I call the `myfunc2` I see this error:

```
 File "~/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    myfunc2()

RuntimeError: missing Environment
```

Anybody has any ideas why calling a function from insdie another is not working in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Numba v0.39+

A fix was introduced in v0.39. As per the [Release Notes](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/release-notes.html#version-0-39-0):

> PR #2986: Fix environment propagation

See [github pull #2986](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/2986) for more details.

#### Numba pre-v0.39

This is a known issue. As described in [github issue #2411](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2411):

> Seems like the environment pointer is not passed properly across
>   nopython functions.

Amending as below to remove `print()` from `numba` functions should fix this:

```
import numba as nb
from math import acos
from time import time

@nb.jit("void()")
def myfunc():
    s = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        s += acos(0.5)
    return s

@nb.jit("void()")
def myfunc2():
    return myfunc()

tic = time()
x = myfunc2()  # 10471975.511390356
toc = time()
print(toc-tic)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working now, but I did not understand exactly what the rule is? Is it the print() statement?

Comment: yes, printing between numba functions does not work because environment pointers are not passed between them.

Comment: what if func is a member in one class, and func2 is in another?